# Envio de informações temporárias entre classes com C# 4.0 MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Trabalho com uma solution VS 2015 que tem 2 sites, "projetoA.site.com.br" e "projetoB.site.com.br", suas views e controllers estão no mesmo projeto, nomeado como "WEB", desenvolvido em C# .NET 4 com MVC 4, porém em duas pastas, "Projeto A" e "Projeto B", ou seja, está tudo organizado.

A situação é a seguinte, quando o usuário acessar o site "projetoA.site.com.br" e clicar em determinada opção, vou direcioná-lo para o site de cadastro, que se encontra no Projeto B, porém um dropdown será preenchido com determinados valores, e caso o usuário recarregue a página, esse dropdown deve ser preenchido com outros valores diferentes.

Tecnicamente é assim, quando o usuário clicar na determinada opção, mencionada acima, será acionado um método no meu controller do Projeto A, que no TempData do MVC eu insiro o valor 1, em seguida chamo o método Index() do controller do Projeto B

*PROJETO A*

**VIEW**

```
<li>
          <a href="@Url.Action(MVC.ProjetoA.Home.AbrirCadastro())"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> Cadastro </a>
</li>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
    [RequiresAuthorization]
    public virtual ActionResult AbrirCadastro()
    {
        Client dadosUsuario = ViewBag.User;
        TempData["Teste"] = 1;
        return Redirect(Url.SubdomainUrl(SubdomainConstants.Register, MVC.ProjetoB.Home.Index()));
    }
```

No método Index() do controller do Projeto B terei uma validação para customizar os valores a serem preenchidos no dropdown.

*PROJETO B*

**CONTROLLER**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public virtual ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (TempData["Teste"] != null)
        {
            //Preencho dropdown de uma maneira
        }
        else
        {
            //Preencho dropdown de outra maneira
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Mas no meu método Index() o TempData vem nulo. Como faço para enviar uma informação do método AbrirCadastro(), no controller do Projeto A, para o método Index(), no controller do Projeto B?

Preciso que seja algo temporário, que somente o método AbrirCadastro() envie, e que não seja exibido na URL, para que não seja rastreavel. Pensei em trabalhar com Session (por isso o TempData) ou com parametros em métodos, porém não sei como ocultar o parametro na URL.

Comment: A questão aqui não é se você pretende fazer essa "troca" de informações entre duas classes. Você precisa pensar no seu projeto como uma aplicação, precisa nos explicar qual fluxo desta forma. O **Projeto A** e o **Projeto B** são o quê? Sites? WebServices?

Comment: São dois sites que acesso via URL, por exemplo, url do **projeto a** "projetoa.site.com.br" e **projeto B** "projetob.site.com.br". O usuário vai se loggar no site do projeto b, vai clicar em uma opção do menu, em seguida preciso enviar um dado temporário da classe do proejto b para a index do site do projeto a. Caso o projeto a receba uma nova requisição, o dado temporário não deve existir.

Comment: Você vai ter que fazer um POST enviado este dado ou algo assim... Este  comentário já ajuda bastante no entendimento da pergunta, mas ainda tá um pouco difícil de entender o que e como você pretende fazer.

Comment: No que está escrito de acessar classes, resumo **"NÃO DÁ"**.

Comment: @FelipeNegro, não importa se tá dentro da mesma *solution*. Se são aplicações diferentes, elas **são aplicações diferentes** e pronto. Você vai ter que usar os recursos disponíveis pra fazer essa comunicação. É claro que, dependendo do caso, pode haver uma comunicação direta, mas pelo que você explicou, essa é a maneira correta. Sinta-se a vontade para [edit] a pergunta e ajudar o entendimento. A princípio é isso mesmo, vai ter que enviar a informação via HTTP.

Comment: @jbueno vou tentar deixar mais claro. O usuário entrará no site "projetoB.site.com.br" com sua conta, haverá no menu uma opção que ele clicando nessa opção deverá abrir o site "projetoA.site.com.br" com um dropdown preenchido com as informações 1, 2 e 3, se ele der um F5 no browser, vai abrir o mesmo site, mas o dropdown preenchido com 5, 6 e 7, basicamente.

Comment: Melhorou mais um pouco, mas ainda tá um pouco confuso. Mantenho o que eu disse, vai ter que enviar a informação via HTTP.

Comment: @jbueno Rsrs. Tem algum artigo que eu possa estudar como fazer o que propos, por favor?

Comment: @FelipeNegro Não sei se entendi bem, mas já pensou em passar esse valor por queryString, por exemplo: **projetoA.site.com.br/Home/Index/valor-aqui** e após carregar a página basta remover a queryString. Assim ao atualizar o valor será diferente.

Comment: Sem entender o que precisa, fica difícil dar sugestões, pois podem não se adequar ao seu contexto

Comment: @Randrade E como poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Editei a pergunta para que fique mais clara

Comment: Os dois estão no mesmo dómínio mesmo?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52016/discussion-between-felipe-negro-and-randrade).

Answer (score 2):

Pressupondo que você possui acesso aos dois sistemas, você poderia realizar realizar um POST do **ProjetoA** para o **ProjetoB** passando um valor. E, no projetoB você verifica se existe esse valor e preenche o seu `TempData`. Um exemplo seria mais ou menos isso:

#### Projeto B

Cire uma Ation POST para receber os dados de outra aplicação. Caso possua valor, você realiza o redirecionamento com o `TempData`. Seria algo desta forma:

```
   // GET: ProjetoB
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string valor = "";
        if (TempData["Teste"] != null)
        {
            valor = "sim";
        }
        else
        {
            valor = "não";
        }

        ViewBag.Valor = valor;
        return View();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string valor)
    {
        //Caso tenha valor, você preenche o TempData
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(valor))
            TempData["Teste"] = 1;

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

> Estou passando o valor para caso queira utilizá-lo em alguma consulta. Mas, para o seu Modelo isso seria irrelevante.

Desta forma, ao atualizar a página o `TempData` terá será `null`, e desta forma você não preenche o `DropDown`.

#### Projeto A

No seu **ProjetoA** basta realizar o POST para a página correta do **ProjetoB**, desta forma:

```
<li>
    @*Na Action você deve passar o valor completo do Action POST do ProjetoB*@
    <form action="/ProjetoB/Index" method="post" id="link-cadastro">
        <input type="hidden" value="true" name="valor" />
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$('#link-cadastro').submit()"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> Cadastro </a>
    </form>
</li>
```

Altere o `action="/ProjetoB/Index"`  para o caminho do `POST` do **ProjetoB**.

Note que estou utilizando somente HTML para uma melhor compreensão. Porém, pode utilizar `HtmlHelpers` normalmente.

Comment: Com esta sua sugestão e algumas diferenças, consegui o que eu precisava, postarei como ficou aqui.

Comment: Na sugestão que propôs para inserir no Projeto A, como ficaria se eu precisasse passar um parâmetro do tipo Hidden?

Answer (score 2):

Uma opção seria trabalhar com [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).

Para ser mais exato, com [cookies por domínios](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#new-cookie_domain).

Segundo o [seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178214/envio-de-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-tempor%C3%A1rias-entre-classes-com-c-4-0-mvc-4/178335#comment368195_178214), ambos sistemas são subdomínios do mesmo domínio, ou seja, todos terminam com **.site.com.br**. Sendo assim, você pode definir um cookie ao clicar no link do **ProjetoA** e excluir na Action Index do **ProjetoB**.

Seria algo parecido com isso:

#### ProjetoA

No **ProjetoA** você criaria uma Action apenas para criar o `cookie` e redirecionar para o **ProjetoB** (pode fazer via JS também, fica a seu critério), desta forma:

```
public ActionResult LinkFake()
{
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("MeuCookie");
    //Define o valor do cookie
    cookie.Value = "valorQualquer";
    //Define o Dominio do cookie
    cookie.Domain = "seudominio.com";
    //Adiciona o cookie
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

    //Redireciona para o ProjetoB
    return RedirectToAction("URL PROJETO B");
}
```

E em sua View, você chamaria a Action `LinkFake()`, desta forma:

```
<li>
    <a href="@Url.Action(LINK DA ACTIONFAKE AQUI)"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> Cadastro </a>
</li>
```

E em Seu **ProjetoB** você apenas verificar se existe aquele `cookie` ou não, desta forma:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["MeuCookie"];

    if(cookie != null)
    {
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        //Preencho dropdown de uma maneira
    }
    else
    {
        //Preencho dropdown de outra maneira
    }

    return View();
}
```

Links de estudos:

- [How do browser cookie domains work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1062963/4843158)
- [Share cookie between subdomain and domain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18492576/4843158)
- [Cross-Domain Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3342140/4843158)

Comment: Não deu certo, quando vou recuperar o valor do Cookie, ele não existe, está nulo.

Comment: @FelipeNegro Os dois estão mesmo no mesmo domínio?

Comment: até onde eu sei, estão. Só consigo chamar o meu método no Projeto B da seguinte maneira "return Redirect(Url.SubdomainUrl(SubdomainConstants.Register, MVC.ProjetoA.Home.Método(Parametro)));"

Comment: @FelipeNegro Essa forma de você chamar as url's é muito "diferente". Não tem como saber o que está nesses valores. Mas, se é **siteA.site.com.br** e **siteB.site.com.br** sendo que **site.com.br** deve ser iguais, são subdomínios.

Comment: Foi a única maneira que consegui chamar no Projeto A, o método no Projeto B. Publiquei o resultado final. Muito obrigado por toda ajuda!!!

Answer (score 0):

Com a ajuda das sugestões do @Randrade, consegui chegar no resultado final conforme abaixo:

**PROJETO A**

A view continua a mesma da pergunta.

*VIEW*

```
<li>
      <a href="@Url.Action(MVC.ProjetoA.Home.AbrirCadastro())"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> Cadastro </a>
</li>
```

Já o Controller não está mais com o TempData e redireciono para um método auxiliar no Projeto B.

*CONTROLLER*

```
[RequiresAuthorization]
public virtual ActionResult AbrirCadastro()
{
    Client dadosUsuario = ViewBag.User;
    return Redirect(Url.SubdomainUrl(SubdomainConstants.Register, MVC.ProjetoB.Home.IndexAuxiliar()));
}
```

**PROJETO B**

*CONTROLLER*

Inseri um método auxiliar para preencher o TempData

```
    [HttpGet]
    public virtual ActionResult IndexAuxiliar()
    {
        TempData["Teste"] = true;
        return RedirectToAction(MVC.ProjetoB.Home.Index());
    }
```

E no método principal eu verifico se está nulo ou não. Assim, quando houver um reload da página, o TempData estará nulo, conseguindo assim o meu objetivo.

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult Index()
{
    if (TempData["Teste"] != null)
    {
        //Preencho dropdown de uma maneira
    }
    else
    {
        //Preencho dropdown de outra maneira
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Eu fiz meu exemplo com POST apenas pq com GET se alguém acessar a IndexAuxiliar pela URl, será direcionado da mesma forma.